# Python function not printing or receiving console values

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, playwright

I intend to make the program ask in the console which browser to use for the test.

When I just place the browser value in the `browser_option = "Firefox"` line it works fine, but when I try and put `browser_option = input("Choose a browser")` it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from locators import Locators_evou
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    browser_option = "Firefox"
    
    def get_browser(self, p):
        browserR = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        if self.browser_option == "":
            self.browser_option = "Chrome"            
        if self.browser_option == "Firefox":
            browserR = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)

        elif self.browser_option == "Edge":
            browserR = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge",headless=False)    
        
        return browserR

#TEST COMPANY REGISTER
    def test_company1(self): 
                 
        with sync_playwright() as p:
                                    
            browser = self.get_browser(p)
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto("http://localhost:3000/organigrama/miempresa-edit")
            browser.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you write `browser_option = input("Choose a browser")`?

Comment: You have a class, your input have to be get in the constructor. But for best practices we do the input at the main then pass it to the constructor of the class.